# How to set model's load order to avoid relation errors?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, model, ember.js, directory-structure

I have a folder `models` for model files. Each file contain one model. There are a lot of relations between models (hasMany, belongsTo). If I want to set hasMany relation then I need to have child model already defined otherwise I get an error:

```
Error: assertion failed: The first argument DS.belongsTo must be a model type or string, like DS.belongsTo(App.Person)
```

Because the model (App.Person in case of upper example) has not defined yet.

Here is one of the relation definition:

> ```
> App.Seat = DS.Model.extend(
>   number: DS.attr('number')
>   tour: DS.belongsTo(App.Tour)
> )
> ```

The models folder included like this:

```
//= require_tree ./models
```

I know the solution to define all the models (or at least which have relationships with each other) in one file.

***Question: is there any other solution that allow to keep all the models in separate files?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a pretty simple solution: define all relation not as an object (ex. `App.Tour`):

```
App.Seat = DS.Model.extend(
  number: DS.attr('number')
  tour: DS.belongsTo(App.Tour) # <<<<<<<<<<<============ ***here***
)
```

but as a string (ex. `"App.Tour"`) so just **put it in quotes**:

```
App.Seat = DS.Model.extend(
      number: DS.attr('number')
      tour: DS.belongsTo("App.Tour") # <<<<<<<<<<<============ ***here***
    )
```

I think that this "workaround" is because of javascript limitation.

**UPDATED**: Using strings is **preferred** by ember.js

Comment: Yup, it's *preferred* to be defined as string since [revision 5](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/BREAKING_CHANGES.md)

Comment: I did that guided by [tests](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/tests/integration/embedded/embedded_without_ids_test.js#L9) and there are used not strings.